# Can proguard '-dontshrink' option only work in library module?

Tags: android, proguard

I use gradle `consumerProguardFiles` option to obfuscate my library module for android project. Then I add proguard's `-dontshrink` option in library's proguard-rules.pro file to protect my library class from being deleted, but `-dontshrink` work for my whole project! 
Is that any way to use proguard `-dontshrink` just work in library module(**need optimize and obfuscate**)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution, use `-keep` with `allowobfuscation` option, it will just obfuscate the code.